# docker-compose complains about missing ']'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get nodemon and docker-compose work with each others and I'm having a problem: Every time I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error: `sh: missing ]`. Here are the relevant files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:11.1.0-alpine

MAINTAINER TileHalo

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --save

COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "nodemon", "./bin/www"]
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:alpine"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: supersalainen
      POSTGRES_USER:  kipa
```

EDIT: Works on pure docker after the comma fix, but doesn't work on docker-compose

Comment: `cmd` needs the arguments separated with commas. `CMD [ "nodemon", "./bin/www"]`

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Try replacing `CMD` with `ENTRYPOINT`. Also, according to [the reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) you need to give the full path of the executable if you are using `CMD`